# Select multiple items in UserForm With Listbox and connect to "database"

Tags: excel, vba

How do I select multiple items in a list box (Invited by|Action Items|Info.) in user form and have it all display in a column in a list box? not sure how to connect the form to database. i copied the module code and the form code below.

[image: As you see the form populates into the database but the ones that have multiple items do not display]

```
    Private Sub cmdReset_Click()
        Dim msgValue As VbMsgBoxResult
        msgValue = MsgBox(" Do you want to reset the form?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirmation")
        If msgValue = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        Call Reset
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
        Dim msgValue As VbMsgBoxResult
        msgValue = MsgBox(" Do you want to save the data?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirmation")
        If msgValue = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        Call Submit
        Call Reset
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstInvited_Initialize()
        Me.lstInvited.RowSource = strInvitedList
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstAction_Initialize()
       Me.lstAction.RowSource = strDVActionList
    End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Call Reset
    End Sub
```

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub Reset()
        Dim iRow As Long
        iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)] ' identifying the last row
        With frmForm
            .txtName.Value = ""
            .txtAge.Value = "'"
            
            .lstInvited.Clear
            .lstInvited.AddItem "S. A"
            .lstInvited.AddItem "S. B"
            .lstInvited.AddItem "S. Br"

            .cmbTeacher.Clear
            .cmbTeacher.AddItem "S. A"
            .cmbTeacher.AddItem "S. B"
            .cmbTeacher.AddItem "S. C"
            
            .cmbStudy.Clear
            .cmbStudy.AddItem "FOS"
            .cmbStudy.AddItem "Saviors"
            .cmbStudy.AddItem "TOL"
            .cmbStudy.AddItem "Jerusalem Mother"
            .cmbStudy.AddItem "HFEF"
            .cmbStudy.AddItem "Keep the Sabbath Day Holy"
            .cmbStudy.AddItem "PWTEL"
            .cmbStudy.AddItem "Cross Reverance"
            .cmbStudy.AddItem "BBI"
            .cmbStudy.AddItem "The Bible is Fact"
            
            .lstAction.Clear
            .lstAction.AddItem "Wants to  again"
            .lstAction.AddItem "Wants to be"
            .lstAction.AddItem "Wants to keep "
            .lstAction.AddItem "Wants to study in person"
            .lstAction.AddItem "Doesn't want to study again"
            .lstAction.AddItem "Other, Please specify in Notes"
        
            .lstInfo.Clear
            .lstInfo.AddItem "Open-minded"
            .lstInfo.AddItem "Went on the internet"
            .lstInfo.AddItem "Needs to study in a different language"
            .lstInfo.AddItem "Need "
            .lstInfo.AddItem "Prefers to study in groups"
            .lstInfo.AddItem "Doesn't believe "
            .lstInfo.AddItem "Doubting "
            .lstInfo.AddItem "Doubting "
            .lstInfo.AddItem "Argumentative / Debater"
            .lstInfo.AddItem "Other, Please specify in Notes"
            
            .lstZoom.Clear
            .lstZoom.AddItem "Attentive"
            .lstZoom.AddItem "Not interactive/ Not connected"
            .lstZoom.AddItem "Occupied"
            .lstZoom.AddItem "Ungracious"
            .lstZoom.AddItem "Other, Please specify in Notes"
            
            .txtNotes.Value = ""
            
            .lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 10
            .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
            
            If iRow > 1 Then
                .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:J" & iRow
            Else
                .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:J2"
            End If
        End With
    End Sub


    Sub Submit()
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Dim iRow As Long
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
        iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)] + 1
        With sh
            .Cells(iRow, 1) = frmForm.txtName.Value
            .Cells(iRow, 2) = frmForm.lstInvited.Value
            .Cells(iRow, 3) = frmForm.txtAge.Value
            .Cells(iRow, 4) = frmForm.cmbTeacher.Value
            .Cells(iRow, 5) = frmForm.cmbStudy.Value
            .Cells(iRow, 6) = frmForm.dtpDate.Value
            .Cells(iRow, 7) = frmForm.lstAction.Value
            .Cells(iRow, 8) = frmForm.lstInfo.Value
            .Cells(iRow, 9) = frmForm.lstZoom.Value
            .Cells(iRow, 10) = frmForm.txtNotes.Value
        End With
    End Sub

    Sub Show_Form()
        frmForm.Show
    End Sub
```

Comment: `iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)]` does not determine the last row. It counts the number of not-empty cells in column A. Is your "database" a worksheet, or do you have a database connection in the workbook you want to use?

Comment: hi @Nacorid the database is a worksheet but is displayed on the bottom of the form as well. i'm not sure if the screenshot is visible